# Problems starting mysqld

Tags: mysql

When I try to start mysqld i get this error.. Any ideas on how to fix this?
Should I run it as sudo? From some tutorial on internet they did not need to use sudo.
I am using MYSQL community edition on Lubuntu 22.04

```
(base) alfredo@alfredo-hpelitebook725g4:~$ mysqld
2022-05-15T19:32:38.246287Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-05-15T19:32:38.246379Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) starting as process 10661
2022-05-15T19:32:38.249975Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-05-15T19:32:38.249987Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2022-05-15T19:32:38.250023Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno: 13 - Permission denied)
2022-05-15T19:32:38.250157Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-05-15T19:32:38.253779Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
(base) alfredo@alfredo-hpelitebook725g4:~$
```

Comment: Have you try to run it with `systemctl`? What is the result of `ls -ld /var/lib/mysql`?

Answer (score 0):

mysqld is not intended to be run by a regular user. Start it via it's systemd unit.

```
sudo systemctl enable mysql
sudo systemctl start mysql
```